# encoding and decoding algorithms in php

Tags: php, encryption

Is is a bad practice to show database values in get method for security point of view? 
for example:- 'http://example.com/user/id/10' where 10 takes value from database.

Please can anyone suggest me a standard encoding and decoding algorithms that takes two parameter (both for encoding and decoding) so that one can be stored as a variable in php file(or in database) and the other parameter being a string to be encoded or decoded.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's no security risk as such. What can a user do with "10"? It depends on the rest of your application whether this opens any security holes or not. Encoding values in the URL is usually the wrong approach for solving security problems that may or may not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would answer the first part of your question:

> Is is a bad practice to show database
>   values in get method for security
>   point of view? for example:-
>   'http://example.com/user/id/10' where
>   10 takes value from database.

Not really, it depends on what the 'page' is doing with the id/10.  If you are simply displaying user information (profile), what is the harm? However if you want to mask your URLs that is all up to you.  I have seen masking using encryption, however I'm curious why you think the URL will be 'harmful' ?  Do you just not want a user to see id = 10?  I would focus on making my php/sql query on that page secure rather than add additional overhead for encrypting something that is harmless (from my point of view).

**EDIT:**

For simplicity sake, you could utilize the php function `base64_encode` and decode: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

That should give you enough. But I really would think about WHY you want to hide it in the first place, generally 'easy to read' urls are always a bonus, especially when it comes to search engine optimization.

Comment: base64 is pretty obvious to anyone who has ever seen it so all it does in my opinion is make the URL longer. Otherwise agreed.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i was just wondering why framework like cakePHP take 'salt' values for encryption. Dosen't it look stupid that i am showing the id (which is the primary key of the database) for all users? i just needed the masking the algorithm. bur base64 encode takes only one parameter? could you suggest me one?

Comment: @explorex, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography), is 'added' to your 'string' that you are encoding, it is quite simply something like 'mystring'+'secretsalt', which makes the encryption just a little more.  I don't think it is stupid if you show the id, I mean look at SO, the questions id, the user id for profiles, its all there, its human readable rather than encrypted gibberish. Focus on your application security rather than the url.

Answer (score 0):

The only risk is if you don't have your site permissions security setup correctly.  Matching your data by database id is fine, it's just easy to understand.  If someone wants to crawl all your data all they have to do is increment the url.

If you don't want people to be able to access certain "ids" just make sure they have the proper login credentials to see that page.

Now if you want to encrypt/decrypt easily, look into using md5 hashes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but md5 has no 'decrypt' function, so how would he get his `id`?

Comment: @waijw can i decrypt with md5

Comment: The keys would have to be stored as encrypted in the database, like a password.  The user would see the hash and not the id in the implementation I was thinking of, though I'm not really sure why it would need to be encrypted in the first place.

Comment: @explorex no you cannot.  md5 is made for one way keys basically.  if you want two way encrypt/decrypt, base64 en/de-code would work for you like the other answer says.  depends on what kind of implementation you want to do.

Comment: @wajiw, sorry no point to your answer if you are encrypting an id to an md5 hash only to look up that hash in the db.

Comment: @jakub it's basic id obfuscation.  stops crawlers from being able to easily increment through data which was my main point in using it.  way to be petty about something unimportant in the argument